# How to convert a string containing symbols and numbers into a list of floats or integers?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list

I have a list in the following format:

```
my_list = ['2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70']
```

As you can see, it contains strings which are intervals.

I am trying to convert this list to the following format:

```
list_of_lists = [[2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], etc....]
```

I have been trying to use the following structure:

```
list_2 = []
for item in my_list:
    list_2.append(list(item))
list_3 = [x for x in list_2 if x != "-"]
list_4 = []
for item_2 in list_3:
    var = float(item_2)
    list_4.append(var)
```

The problem with this code is that it converts two digit numbers into two separate numbers. Also, overall, it feels like this is not an optimum solution.

Can anybody give a guidance or an advice, please?

Cheers :) 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right track, but the key thing you're missing is the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method that can do most of the heavy lifting here.

Also, I personally would use a list comprehension at the top level to simplify the code:

```
>>> [map(float, el.split('-')) for el in my_list]
[[2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0], [2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0], [2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0]]
```

Here:

- `[... el in my_list]` iterates over the strings in `my_list`, applies an expression (not shown) to each element, and returns the results as a list;
- `el.split('-')` splits each element at the dash, converting each string into a list of strings;
- `map(float, ...)` converts each string in the sub-list into a float.

Comment: I believe the output is: `[<map object at 0x7f283eccf1d0>, <map object at 0x7f283eccffd0>, <map object at 0x7f283ece70b8>, <map object at 0x7f283ece7198>, <map object at 0x7f283ece7208>, <map object at 0x7f283ece72e8>, <map object at 0x7f283ece7400>, <map object at 0x7f283ece7518>, <map object at 0x7f283ece75c0>, <map object at 0x7f283ece76d8>, <map object at 0x7f283ece77f0>, <map object at 0x7f283ece7908>]`

Comment: Not on Python 2 as in the tag.

Comment: @depperm Question is tagged Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

Try the split function and map function

```
list_2 = []
for item in my_list:
    list_2.append(list(map(float,item.split('-'))))
```

Comment: Lack of explanation may be. Considering OP is struggling with basic split there should be some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
my_list = ['2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70']

list_2 = []

for val in my_list:
  x , y = map(float, val.split('-'))
  list_2.append([x, y])

print(list_2)
```

Output:

```
[[2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0], [2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0], [2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ['2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', 
           '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', 
           '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70']

list_2 = []
for item in my_list:
    first, second = item.split('-')
    list_2.append([float(first), float(second)])
```

Every item in your original list `my_list` is by the `split()` method divided into two parts and assigned to the variables `first` and `second`, respectively.

As they are still *strings*, in the last command I used the `float()` function to convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative if you don't want to use the map function:

```
my_list = ['2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70']

my_list_1 = [ [float(elem.split('-')[0]), float(elem.split('-')[1])] for elem in my_list]
print list_1
```

OR

```
my_list = ['2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70', '2-7', '10-22', '22-50', '50-70']

my_list_1 = [ [float(elem[0]), float(elem[1])] for elem in [elem.split('-') for elem in my_list]]
print list_1
```

Here is the result in both the cases:

```
[[2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0], [2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0], [2.0, 7.0], [10.0, 22.0], [22.0, 50.0], [50.0, 70.0]]
```

Comment: Maybe avoid splitting twice?